# When did John Crichton start calling his gun Winona?

Tags: weapon, farscape

I watched Farscape fairly religiously back when it was first aired on the BBC.
I've caught some episodes recently sitting up with my teething Son, and found myself asking ...

At what point did John start calling his gun Winona, and why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**In *A Clockwork Nebari* (S02E18)**

The name actually came from Ben Browder, and is a reference to Winona Ryder. I've heard both that it's because another cast member of that episode reminded him of Johnny Depp, and because of Ryder's role in Alien: Resurrection. I don't know if either/both are true.

I've also seen a quote from Browder that all guns should be named after beautiful women. I don't know if he's named any others in other shows, though.

In-universe, it just seems like the sort of thing that Crichton would do - a reference to an Earth actress, naming a weapon - those all fit the character. I don't think there's any in-universe explanation for Winona specifically, other than she's female and famous.

Comment: Lots of examples of naming weapons here: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ICallItVera

Comment: Yet his character didn't name a gun he liked in SG-1 (I think it was an H&K G36, but I could be wrong).  But perhaps that's because it was an armory weapon and not one assigned or owned by him.

Comment: @MBraedley: That was a completely different character.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Answer says the "all guns should be.." quote is from the actor, not the character, so it is sort-of relevant

Comment: Downvoted because, unfortunately, wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The first time John refers to his beloved pulse pistol as Winona is at the beginning of "Clockwork Nebari" towards the end of season 2.  The male Nebari character in that episode reminded Ben of Johnny Deps famous Edward Scissor Hands, I guess that put winona on his mind!

Answer (score 0):

In-universe, John found his favored pulse pistol in [Farscape: The Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farscape:_The_Game), set *prior* to its first on-screen appearance in ['A Clockwork Nebari'](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/A_Clockwork_Nebari)

> **Crichton:** [finds a pulse pistol] *What do we have here? A pulse pistol. What are you doing here on your own? You're going to come in
>   handy. **You need a name... Winona. I'm gonna call you Winona.***

There's no indication why he chose this particular name.

---

Out of universe, Ben Browder personally chose the name of his character's gun, naming it after actress [**Winona Ryder**](http://41.media.tumblr.com/7c46f977d7d4c39cf1af1bf339916df5/tumblr_n8uondqFdH1rrhpedo1_500.jpg)

> **Q. *Who or what is the antecedent for John naming his pulse pistol 
>   "Wynonna"? ... (And do we finally have the spelling right? )***
>
> **BB:** *Winona Ryder. I continue to screw up the spelling of that one. All important inanimate objects should be named after beautiful
>   women. My biggest regret is that I never seized upon the opportunity
>   to name the Farscape module... But in my soul, I call her "Betty".*
>
> <sub><sup>[Farscape World - Ask Ben](http://www.farscapeworld.com/interviews/interviews.php?id=askben)</sup></sub>

Answer (score -2):

The first instance I can recall him using that name is in "Green Eyed Monster" S3E8.

Comment: Sean, there's already an answer to this question that has a provable answer. I can't imagine it being wrong, but feel free to argue your case :)